# How can I put an ng-valid on a fieldset in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if one could make it so in AngularJS ,without resorting to any custom directives, that if all fields inside a fieldset are valid, the fieldset itself would also get a class 'ng-valid'

Say, I have this:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Hello</legend>
  <input type="email" ng-model="user.email">
</fieldset>
```

What I would like, if someone enters something valid inside the input, you would get

```
<fieldset class="ng-valid">
  <legend>Hello</legend>
  <input type="email" ng-model="user.email">
</fieldset>
```

**UPDATE: So I started doing this**

```
app.directive('validatedmarker', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: { },

    link: function(scope,e,a) {
        var el = $(e).find('input');
        var pristine = el.hasClass('ng-pristine'),
            invalid = el.hasClass('ng-invalid');


        scope.$watch('user.name', function() {
            console.log('foo')
        });
    }

};
});
```

Totally expecting scope.$watch to fire, but it doesn't...
The HTML looks like this.

```
<fieldset validatedmarker>
        <legend>User</legend>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        {{user.name}}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

So I was thinking if I change the model user.name, the $watch would fire and I could check if it has valid/invalid fields. Of course I would like to check the whole 'user' model. But for now, I would be a happy camper if this would work.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? 
Thanks!
Marco

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Well, not so much since I am learning- and trying to wrap my head around all the different concepts and wondering if it's all possible just using the core Angular directives.

Comment: So it seems the above code seems to work, however only in Angular 1.0x, not in 1.2. I'm stumped why that is...